# Can I make Swing JButtons have smaller margins?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, margin

I prefer buttons with minimal margins, about as wide as their text caption. Is there a way to achieve that in a JButton in Swing?

What I am seeing in practice now is that even if I try to use setMaximumSize() and similar, it just ends up eating the text caption, cutting it off to the right. But it does not reduce the margins.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe [`setMargin`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)) is what you're looking for.

```
myButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting you can make the values for Insets -ve (EDIT: read *negative*). This makes things even more compact and if done carefully doesn't look unpleasant.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What do you mean?

Comment: You can do new Insets(0,-4,0,-4); and it makes things even smaller.