# Java Swing GridBagLayout - adding buttons without space

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

How can I remove spacing caused by gridBagLayout and make them stick together?
Here is my code simply adding 3 buttons.
I read this question but there was no complete solution  [How to fix gap in GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972904/how-to-fix-gap-in-gridbaglayout);
I just want to put all of my buttons on the top of the JFrame.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyProblem {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyProblem();
    }

    public MyProblem() {
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            jPanel.setSize(80, 80);
            jPanel.add(new JButton("Button " + i),BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            frame.add(jPanel, gc);
            gc.gridy++;
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**How my buttons look like:**
[image]
**How I want my buttons to look like:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Borr for your revision :).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328405/jpanel-padding-in-java) for `JLabel` and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954674/can-i-make-swing-jbuttons-have-smaller-margins) for `JButton`.

Comment: Thank you but in this question he/she wants to add spacing but I want to remove spacing. The second one also didn't worked.

Comment: Please check the second link. Also I do believe you're allowed to supply negative values to the margin values.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I put it to negative and some of the content of button disappred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyProblem {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyProblem();
    }

    public MyProblem() {
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.ipadx = 0;
        gc.ipady = 0;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button " + i);
            frame.add(button, gc);
            gc.gridy++;
        }
        gc.weighty = 1;
        frame.add(Box.createGlue(), gc); //Adding a component to feel the area.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Box.createGlue()` ... `<head-desk/>` I had the vague feeling I was forgetting something ***important*** about GBL and .. **that was it.**  Plus one for the best solution (and discovering it without any help from me!).  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: ..What?  Why give my answer the tick when yours is the *better answer?!?*  You cannot *accept* your own answer immediately (from memory it is 2 days), but when you do, you get a shiny new badge (something like 'self taught' AFAIR).

Answer (score 4):

The layout makes a single column of buttons, so..

Change:

```
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

To:

```
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

### Edit 1

> I want to keep buttons to the same height as described in picture and just putting them at the top.

To constrain them to the top is fairly easy using a combined layout.  In this case we might add the panel with the buttons into the `PAGE_START` of a panel with `BorderLayout`.  That part of a border layout will stretch the **width** of the child component (our panel with `GridLayout`) to fill the available space, but it will *respect the height* of whatever is in it - giving the component only as much vertical space as it needs.

### Edit 2

Here is an MCVE that implements the idea described above.  The outer panel (with a cyan colored border) is used to constrain the height of the button panel (with orange border).  See the comments in the source for more detail on how it works.

[image] [image]  [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MyProblem {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyProblem();
    }

    public MyProblem() {
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // actually the default

        // we will use this panel to constrain the panel with buttons
        JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(ui);
        ui.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 3));

        // the panel (with GridLayout) for the buttons
        JPanel toolPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,0,4)); // added some gap
        toolPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 3));
        // toolPanel will appear at the top of the ui panel
        ui.add(toolPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            toolPanel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setSize(500, 500); // instead..
        frame.pack(); // pack will make it as small as it can be.
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize()); // nice tweak..
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really didn't understand what are my two panels and what are they layout manager.

Comment: Panel 1 has either `GridBagLayout` or (simpler) a `GridLayout` to contain the buttons in a single column.  Panel 2 has a single component (panel 1) in the `PAGE_START`.

Comment: Can you include your code?
I didn't succeed. I updated my question with how I want them to look like.

Comment: I'll consider adding my code, after you show me an MCVE of your best attempt (as I'd advised you post 23 hours ago).

Comment: .. Where is the 2nd panel?  That would have been a good MCVE at the start of the question, but I thought you were clear that my suggestion requires two panels, so I expected to see an attempt ..including a 2nd panel.

Comment: I really didn't understand what you mean by second Panel.

Comment: I Added buttons to JPanel with Border Layout still not working.

Comment: Have a look over the 2nd edit and see if you can understand what it does.  Note that I changed from `GridBagLayout` to `GridLayout` for the button panel because the 2nd stretched the button horizontally (automatically) and was fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code I think you will get help from it

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Think {

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    JButton jbnButton;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    jbnButton = new JButton("Button 1");
    gBC.weightx = 0.5;
    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(jbnButton, gBC);

    jbnButton = new JButton("Button 3");
    gBC.gridx = 2;
    gBC.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(jbnButton, gBC);

    jbnButton = new JButton("Button 4");
    gBC.ipady = 40;     //This component has more breadth compared to other buttons
    gBC.weightx = 0.0;
    gBC.gridwidth = 3;
    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(jbnButton, gBC);

}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Source Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't what I want.